Roll D100 with twenty D6 dices
I have 20 d6 dices and want to simulate d100 dice. My idea is when it is 6 on dice, I will count it as 0, and therefor if I roll twenty d6 I will add each dice and get needed result for d100. In game I am playing the higher result the worse. So, my question is following - if I simulate d100 roll using 20 d6 will it affect randomness in some way that some numbers higher or lower will have more probability?

What is the probability of you rolling a total of 0? What is the probability of you rolling a total of 1?

With your simulation (or any other simulation using predetermined number of d6), probability of getting some result is $N / 6^k$, where $N$ is number of combinations leading to this result. However, probability of getting $1$ on d100 is $1/100$, which is not equal to $N / 6^k$ for any integer $N, k$.

if I roll all 0 it will count as 100

@mihaild, and k is?

$k$ is maximum number of d6 you can roll.

@OlegDobra can you, by blomp's question, give a number - what is probability of rolling total of 0 on 20d6? And what is probability of rolling 100 on 1d100?

You are asking if a sum of $k$ uniformly distributed random integer variables in the range $[0,n]$ is uniformly distributed variable in the range $[0,kn]$
Short story: No, it is definitely not. It will approach a normal distribution as you increase $k$.
To roll 0 with your d6 dies, you would have to roll a "0" 20 times in a row. That's a $\frac{1}{6^{20}}$ chance of happening. That's less than 1 in a million billion chances ($10^{-15}$) of happening.
I would say your proposed method is quite far from the expected 1%
Here is  a simulated distribution of the sum of 20 6-sided dies over one million attempts:

So it is clearly not uniform. It would be a very poor way to simulate a 100-sided die: you're gonna get "average rolls" much more often, almost never any "extreme roll".  Note that in a million simulated attempts, I didn't get a single result below 20 or above 80.
Here is the python code if you wanna try it for yourself:
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

N = int(1e6)
results = [sum(np.random.uniform(low=0, high=5, size=20)) for i in range(N)]
plt.hist(results, bins=50, density=True)
plt.show()


Here are exact counts if you want to update your chart.

@DanielMathias I think OP has enough elements to answer his questions. Worth noting that the y-axis in my hastily-made graph does not correspond to a probability, but just to a normalized count. The histogram being arbitrarily discretized over 50 bins in the min-max range obtained, it does not quite correspond to the proba of each value. It could easily be made a more informative graph with a couple more lines, but I officially deem it good enough for the purposes of this question.

The non-uniformity of the method you describe has been established by others, I'll address the underlying replication problem
One way to solve the replication problem is to note that $6^3=216$ is only slightly larger than $200$.  So, consider ordered triplets of rolls.  There are $216$ of these, and they are all equally probable.  Assign two of these to each value from $1$ to $100$.  Then, when you toss the triple, you get what you want uniformly, unless you are unlucky enough to hit one of the unmatched $16$.  In that case you re-roll.
In theory it could take you arbitrarily many trials to produce an outcome, but in practice you'll get what you want very quickly.  After all, the probability of failure in a single trial is only $$\frac {16}{216}\approx .074$$  so the probability of failing, say, $5$ times in a row is about $.074^5$ or about $1$ in $500,000$.
Alternatively, you can use a sequence of tosses to get a base $6$ "decimal" $\alpha$.  Then you find $i\in \{1,\cdots, 100\}$ such that $$\frac {i-1}{100}<\alpha<\frac i{100}$$ and assign $i$ as the outcome.  Again, in theory it might take arbitrarily many digits to decide what $i$ is, but in practice this will go quickly.
Should point out:  any method you use will have some "bad" cases which take arbitrarily long to decide.  After all, in any outcome of tossing the $d6$, the probability of each event is rational with denominator $6^k$ for some $k$. You can't get $\frac 1{100}$ that way, but you certainly can approximate it.
